# VBA disable pop ups

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code where I am copying sheets from one excel to another one. There are names that have to be copied over. Whenever that happens, there is a pop up (see below) that I wish to disable. I have tried all of the below, and none seem to work. It seems to work on some computers and not on the others, so there might be something with excel settings.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Const ProcName As String = "ListSheets"
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
Dim IsSuccess As Boolean
```

[image: Error]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this enough to confirm that it will solve your issues, but this might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.setwarnings

Comment: are the names duplicative between the source and destination?  If so, why not just delete the names out of the destination and then copy over the ones from the source?

Comment: Thank you both. @sous2817 is there a way to delete all the names in one go? The problem is that I am copying over hundreds of names, and I don't want to risk any breaks. Also it is odd as it only happens in some computers. Are there any settings that i have to turn on?

Comment: Deleting named ranges is very quick. Have a look here to see how to do it in VBA: https://www.exceldemy.com/delete-named-range-in-excel/#3_Insert_VBA_Codes_to_Delete_Name_Ranges

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False` just before opening command lines

Comment: I already have this one. Thanks anyway